# prevent duplicates while inserting records in RabbitMq

Tags: java, rabbitmq, queue

Please suggest how to prevent  insert duplicate records in RabbitMQ Queue using java using values.

Example :

```
{
  "jsonObject" : {
     "code" : "ABC",
     "number" : "123456",
     "Name"  : "Narasimha"
  } 
}
```

if one record available in RabbitMq . if  try to insert one more record with same code and number it should  not allow to insert RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with RabbitMQ, the amqp body is a buffer and RMQ does not know anything about the body content.

You should handle duplications consumer side.

Read here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html

> At the Consumer
>
> In the event of network failure (or a node crashing), messages can be
>   duplicated, and consumers must be prepared to handle them. If
>   possible, the simplest way to handle this is to ensure that your
>   consumers handle messages in an idempotent way rather than explicitly
>   deal with deduplication.